# How to get integer value from IntPtr-parameter in managed delegate that is called from native function with void *?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, managed

I have native function

```
void SetValue(char *FieldName, void *pValue);
```

and I want to change it to call earlier set callback/delegate

that has signature

```
void SetValueDelegate(string fieldName, IntPtr value);
```

I call native SetValue like this:

```
int IntValue = 0;
SetValue("MyField", &IntValue);
```

Now i thought that I can just cast it in managed delegate:

```
void SetValueDelegate(string fieldName, IntPtr value)
{
    if (fieldName == "MyField")
    {
        int intValue = (int)value;
    }
}
```

this is not working. If cast to long it's value is 204790096.

How this should be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your managed code, `value` is the address of the `int` variable. Therefore, you read that variable like this:

```
int intValue = Marshal.ReadInt32(value);
```

Your code is simply reading the address, rather than the value stored at that address.

Comment: thanks! that is naturally true. I found another way: (int)Marshal.PtrToStructure(value, typeof(int)); but your answer is more clear.

Comment: That works too, but `ReadInt32` avoids boxing and unboxing steps I suppose.